# when work CommandBehavior.CloseConnection

Tags: ado.net

```
using(var reader = command.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection))
{
    while(reader.read())
    {
        //calculations
    }
}
```

At what point will close the connection and whether the accumulated opened connection?

Comment: What do you mean by "whether the accumulated opened connection"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.commandbehavior.aspx):

> When the command is executed, the associated `Connection` object is
>   closed when the associated `DataReader` object is closed.

In your case the connection will be closed at the end of the using block.